# Is there a chance to run all asserts from a NightWatch.js test, even if one of the asserts fail?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, nightwatch.js

I want to ask you if there is a chance to run a test with nightwatch and in case of one of the asserts are failing, or some error happens, the test verify all the remaining asserts.  I know that you can use 
`"skip_testcases_on_fail" : false`, but I need to verify all the asserts from a single test. PS: Thank for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assert you could use verify. Verify doesn't fail the test when it fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know about verify, but i'm curious if this problem can be solved without using verify or if a workaround exists for it.  PS: sorry that I didn't mention it from the begining.

Comment: @nightWatchMan How can I use Verify in unit test? would you please help me

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by waitForElementVisible

Instead of

```
browser.verify.visible('elementA') // assume this one will return fail
       .verify.sibible('elementB') 
       .verify.sibible('elementC')
```

We do this

```
   browser.waitForElementVisible('elementA',5000,function(result){
        if(result.value === true) {
           this.verify.sibible('elementB') 
               .verify.sibible('elementC')
          } else {
            console.log('this does not return fail although elementA was visible');
           this.verify.sibible('elementD') 
               .verify.sibible('elementE')
           }

   })
```

But what is the purpose for this "ignore failures"

Comment: I have to change some test because of a massive fixtures changes and in my case it's easier to verify lots of asserts at once, it's not important for me that the test is failing, because I know that. Thanks a lot for the response, I can't upvote because I don't have permission yet, but I will.   PS: I saw a lots of configuration options and I thought that it can be made from a configuration option.

Comment: I know that you can use waitForElementVisible like this if you want to continue even if it's not visible, 
```browser.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000, false);```